# Trying to create a real-time shared browser app using web technologies/languages

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome-extension, webrtc, chromium

I recently came up with a fun (but difficult) side-project idea for a browser instance that can be shared across multiple people. Essentially, you share the same browser session with you and your buddies, and everyone can see and perform the same actions that you would normally be able to do alone. In this case however, the changes affect everyone (Ex. closing a tab for you closes the tab for everyone, everyone watches the same YT video).

All in all, the process will go something like this.

1. I open the browser (session)
2. I send a unique link provided by the browser session to my friend
3. My friend opens the link and is led to the same browser session as me
4. We both have a real-time view of each other's browser and can perform various actions that reflect to all party members
5. The specific session ends when all the users leave the session (or something like that)

Remind you of something? Hint: *Zoom*

Being a web developer, something like this seems like a project that would involve mainly backend work which I not too familiar with. Chromium seems like a good open-source option to code with for the actual browser but the session sharing features seem a bit daunting. I could create a basic browser from scratch or make it into a chrome extension like [Netflix Party](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/netflix-party/mmnbenehknklpbendgmgngeaignppnbe?hl=en) but there obviously has to be a backend somewhere, somehow.

Would love to hear some opinions from you guys. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very interesting side project to improve your skills.  I think I would go for [WebRTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API).  WebRTC provides the API and protocols for P2P connections.  The users can send and receive events realtime through browsers.

If you want to control the party with a central server, you might want to use [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket).

With a simple toy project on the textbook I tend to lose the motivation to complete learning the whole technology.  But your project seems to be quite challenging.  It will be fun to learn all these technologies for sure!  Happy coding!